# Should there be an absolute value inside a radical after simplifying the radicals power?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I am trying to help my sibling with math but their teacher seems to want an absolute value **inside** the radical when simplifying the radical's power, not just outside, which some teachers care and some don't. I am not sure how to do it.

One example problem here:

[image]

I got $ \ x · \sqrt{5xy} \ $
but the teacher said absolute values should be in some answers. I assume the answer was $ \ x · \sqrt{5|x||y|} \ . \ $ I first simplified the $ \ x^{12} \ $ and then converted the radicals to fractional exponents, which were both 4/8 and then simplified them to 1/2.

Another problem:[image]

I obtained $ \ 2 · x^4 · y^9 · \sqrt[4]{2^2} · \sqrt[4]{x^2} \ \ . \ $
I assume this answer would be $ \ 2 · x^4 · y^9 · \sqrt{2|x|} \ \ . $

Do you add an absolute value after simplifying a fractional exponent if the base is a variable? I cannot find any examples of this anywhere online. Does anyone have an example of a problem where there are absolute values inside the radical?

Comment: You can try some examples. For instance see what happens if $x=-2$ and $y=3$.

Comment: The rule for using an absolute-value sign on the variable would be to do so when an even-root is taken of an even power of the variable.  Even-roots (square-roots, fourth-roots, etc.) can only produce positive values or zero and even powers of (real) numbers are always positive or zero.  So we have, for instance, $$ \ \sqrt[4]{9^6} \ \ = \ \ 9^{6/4} \ \ = \ \ 27 \ \ , \ \text{but also} \ \ \sqrt[4]{[-9]^6} \ \ = \ \ 9^{6/4} \ \ = \ \ 27 \ \ . \ $$  The original sign of $ \ x \ $ is "lost", so we have $ \ \sqrt[4]{x^6} \ = \ |x|·\sqrt{|x|} \ \ . $

Comment: Here are a couple conventions to follow with even roots (square root, fourth root, eighth root, etc): 
1)The expression inside the root needs to be non-negative. So include an absolute value inside when the expression can be negative. (It looks like you know this convention)


2) The overall answer is needs to be non-negative, so you may also need absolute values outside.

For your examples, the first comes out to $|x|\sqrt{5|xy|}$, with the extra absolute values on the x out front. For the second, $2x^4|y|^9\sqrt{2|x|}$